# How to put condition in python lambda function

Tags: python, lambda

I want to get the username with max suffix. So, the output for the res should be user0002. I want to ignore if the Username doesn't contain prefix `user` (this data actually throws exception). How to put the condition in lambda function to ignore the prefix other than `user`.

```
res = [{ "Username": "user0001"},{ "Username": "user0002"} {"Username": "test"}]
max_user_id = max(res, key=lambda x:int(x['Username'].split("user")[1]))
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does Python have a ternary conditional operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394809/does-python-have-a-ternary-conditional-operator)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
max([value for entry in res for value in entry.values() if value.startswith("user")])
```

I personally don't like this long list of comprehensions, but this does what you want, and maybe you can take it from here :).

Answer (score 0):

```python
max_user_id = max(res, key=lambda x:int(re.split(r"^user(\d+).*$", x['Username'])[1]) if len(re.split(r"^user(\d+).*$", x['Username'])) > 1 else 0)
```

Messy but can be used